# what is "a backyard project"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

"Jennings is the founder of Mambo, the Australian surf-wear brand famous for its cheeky prints. It started as a backyard project in the 1980s and grew into a multi-million dollar company with 22 stores worldwide."

source:http://money.cnn.com/2016/03/10/smallbusiness/dare-jennings-australia-surfing/index.html?iid=INTL_SPC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It refers to that fact that the project was at the beginning  a small one developed at home (backyard) and then became a multi-billion business.

Many projects especially in the tech business were first developed at home, often in the garage( Apple, Microsoft etc.) and than became huge international companies.